# componentDidMount is rendering continuously in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My aim is to add an splash screen with progress bar in it, so i used [react-native-progress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress) as library for progress bar. And added the screen as initial route, by performing logincheck.

I am using redux, so i created a action in order to perform the progress process in the progress bar, the code for the action as follows:

```
 export const progressBarLevel = () => {
return (dispatch) => {
    this.progress = 0;
    dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: 0 });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.indeterminate = false;
        setInterval(() => {
            this.progress += Math.random()/5;
            if(this.progress > 1){
                this.progress = 1;
            }
            return dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: this.progress });
        },250)
    },500)
}
}
```

Then, connected this to an reducer to save the progress. And then took the piece of progress state into the splash screen and connected via props.

Now whats happening is, i have called the progress action and login check action from componentDidMount(), as both working correctly. But for some reason the progress action is running infinitely, as i have console logged the action, " return dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: this.progress }); " this is getting dispatched infinitely. I couldn't find the origin of the mistake.

My componenetDidMount() :

```
 componentWillMount() {
    this.props.loginCheck(() => {
        this.setState({ isUserAvailble: true})
    })
   this.props.progressBarLevel();
}
```

My Progressbar code:

```
<View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <ProgressBar progress={this.props.progressed} width={200} borderColor="#fff" color="#fff"/>
                </View>
```

I couldnt understand the problem, how to stop the continuous rendering. I even tried this using componentWillMount, there also i am getting continuous action dispatch.

Please guide.

**Update**

Assigning variable to setInterval and then calling it using clearInterval solved the problem

**Updated Code**

```
this.progress = 0;
    dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: 0 });
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.indeterminate = false;
       const interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.progress += Math.random()/5;
            if(this.progress > 1){
                this.progress = 1;
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
            return dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: this.progress });
        },250)
    },500)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I think the problem is setInterval method in action dispatch.

It is not getting cleared and updating your state tree.

**Edit 1:**
You can try below code for a clear interval.

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.progress += Math.random()/5;
            if(this.progress > 1){
                this.progress = 1;
            }
            if(this.progress === 1 && this.interval){
          clearInterval(this.interval);
}
            return dispatch({ type: PROGRESS, payload: this.progress });
        },250)
```

Comment: I have assigned a variable to setInterval and called using clearInterval(variable). Which stopped setInterval. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: If it has solved your problem please accept the answer.